# Uncaught TypeError: t.querySelectorAll is not a function when initialiazing Embedded Tweets

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I'm using the Embedded Tweets API from Twitter.
Everything works great if I have the html markdown from page load.
It also works great if I use the option to add content later, and load the tweets by ID:

```
twttr.widgets.load(
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

This is in the documentation here: https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/initialization#init

But If I try to load the tweets by class name with this:

```
twttr.widgets.load(
  document.getElementsByClassName("containers")
);
```

I'm getting this error inside Twitter's widget.js:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.querySelectorAll is not a function
```

If I log the group of elements to the console, I have a proper group:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug on Twitter's widget?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

As of July 28th 2015, the `getElementsByClassName` example has been removed from Twitter's documentation thanks to another post I made on the Twitter Dev Forums

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may come from the fact that `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) type which is not real javascript `Array` object. On the other hand, `widgets.load` expects either a single element or an `Array` of elements. This leads nodeList to be treated as a single element and the library tries to call `querySelectorAll` on it which is not available for `NodeList` types.

A solution would be to convert that nodeList to a real array when passing it to widgets.load.

One way:

```
twttr.widgets.load(
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("containers"))
);
```

*This works, because a NodeList has a `length` property and is indexable*.

Answer (score 0):

According to twitter's documentation, `load()` accepts either no param or a single element.

> Called without argument, widgets-js will search the entire document.body DOM tree for uninitialized widgets. For better performance, **pass *an* HTMLElement object** to restrict the search only to children of the element.

Since `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, you can't pass that directly. Instead you could pass the first element in the collection like this

```
twttr.widgets.load(
  document.getElementsByClassName("containers")[0];
);
```